# How to wake Selector for OP_WRITE event (java NIO)?

Tags: java, sockets

I want to create a selector for the UDP channel to be able to read and write data on the same stream. But I don't know how to write data from another stream to the socket registered in the selector previously.

I tried using the socket directly but then the selector didn't block anymore.

I have also found a way to use System.in, but it only works on consoles.

QuickData: bytes []

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.DatagramChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;

public class UdpChannelService extends Thread {
    private static final int KB = 1024;
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 128 * KB;
    public static final String IP_HOST = "localhost";
    public static final int IP_PORT = 4040;

    private DatagramChannel channel;
    private Selector selector;
    private SelectionKey key;
    private ByteBuffer bfreader;
    private ByteBuffer bfwriter;
    private boolean running;
    private boolean autoconnect;
    private SocketAddress serverAddress;

    public UdpChannelService() throws IOException {
        running = false;
        autoconnect = false;
        bfreader = ByteBuffer.allocate(BUFFER_SIZE);
        bfwriter = ByteBuffer.allocate(BUFFER_SIZE);
        selector = Selector.open();
        serverAddress = new InetSocketAddress(IP_HOST, IP_PORT);
        channel = createUdpChannel(selector);
    }

    public static DatagramChannel createUdpChannel(Selector selector) throws IOException {
        DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();
        channel.configureBlocking(false);
        channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ|SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
        return channel;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        running = true;

        while (running){
            bfreader.clear();
            try {
                //Doi su kien
                selector.select();
                key = selector.selectedKeys().iterator().next();
                selector.selectedKeys().clear();

                if(!key.isValid())
                    continue;

                if(key.isReadable()){
                    //do du lieu
                    SocketAddress address = channel.receive(bfreader);

                    //chuyen doi du lieu
                    bfreader.flip();
                    QuickData data = QuickData.extract(bfreader);

                    System.out.println(data);

                }

                if(key.isWritable()){
                    bfwriter.flip();
                    channel.send(bfwriter, serverAddress);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void channelWrite(QuickData data) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        bfwriter.put(data.toByteBuffer());
        synchronized (selector){
            if (selector.selectedKeys().isEmpty())
                selector.selectedKeys().add(key);
            selector.wakeup();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        UdpChannelService service = new UdpChannelService();

        service.start();

        while (true){
            service.channelWrite(QuickData.create("111","222",new byte[100]));
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just write, and if you get zero bytes written then you start needing to use OP_WRITE. You don't need the selector's 'permission' to write, unless you had just previously encountered this condition. I don't understand what you mean by "selector didn't block any more" if you already tried this. I also don't know why you're talking about streams in connection with UDP. It's a datagram protocol, not a streaming protocol. NB You should `flip()` before `send()` and `compact()` or `clear()` afterwards.

Comment: It seems my question is not enough.
"selector didn't block any more": it was time for me to interfere with the element of the selector and then the selector went from blocking to non blocking. ie it received no event but opened the stream to run OP_READ event and I lost control of the selector.
Second thing: I think my main purpose for this is to create a stream to read audio recording to save the maximum flow, before I have to create 2 streams to read audio recording and is very memory consuming. as ineffective.
What you don't understand may be due to the language.

Comment: You don't have to interfere with the selector to write. I've already said that. Just write. Only when you get a zero length write do you need to do that, and then you need to wakeup the selector before changing `interestOps`.